# Third party Blocking js - google insights

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Hi we are failing google insights coz of these scripts.
Google/Doubleclick Ads,Google Analytics,Other Google APIs/SDKs,Google Tag Manager.
Can someone please help me how to solve it. Website is in drupal.
Any specific code used to delay the scripts. We are already using async but its not working.